# What would be the simplest XAML code to databind this compound (collection) object (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, collections

Taking the code of [this WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14477620) (or what is the same, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14474077)), databinding a а collection (List object (myOrders):

1. **What would be more simple (the simplest possible) XAML script for
   such binding, i.e. to bind a collection object?**
2. Related question based on the same code example:
   [How to change this XAML code to align rows and add headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504467/how-to-change-this-xaml-code-to-align-rows-and-add-headers)

Answer (score 1):

You could project your Order collection into a Part collection, wrapping each element in a ViewModel class which knows its parent order and if it should display its label in the "Order name" collumn or not.
It would be something like (I have not tested!):

```
public class PartWrapper{
    public Part Part{ get; set;}
    public Order Order{ get; set;}
    public bool ShowOrder{ get; set;}

    public PartWrapper(Part part, Order order, bool showOrder){
        this.Part = part;
        this.Order = order;
        this.ShowOrder = showOrder;
    }
}

var items = this.orders.SelectMany(o => o.Parts.Select(p => new PartWrapper(p, o, false)) ).ToList();
foreach(var item in items.GroupBy(i => i.Order).Select(g => g.First()))
    item.ShowOrder = true;
```

Comment: The main question was how to use (simpler) one binding of a compound object in XAML instead of current (complex) multiple bindings of its parts and I still have no clue how to do it