# How to change this XAML code to align rows and add headers?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, data-binding

Taking the code of [this WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14477620) (or what is the same, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14474077)), databinding a а collection (List object (myOrders):

1. how to place OrderName in one line with the first line of PartNmae
   and PartQuantity?
2. how to add common headers on top of columns?

That is in place of current

[image]

I'd like to produce:

```
Order Name       Part Name  Quantity  
Order1           Part11     11  
                 Part12     12  

Order2           Part21     22 
                 Part22     22  
                 Part23     23
```

Related question based on the same code example:

- [What would be the simplest XAML code to databind compound (collection) object (WPF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502530/how-to-refractor-xaml-code-databinding-compound-object-wpf)

**Update (addressing advise about using DataGrid):**
The question was about how to hack the formatting in case in TreeView-like manner...

DataGrid permits to collapse/expand parts of the collection or make master/detail views but I could not find how to suppress repeating values, i.e. in this case of OrderName:

```
Order Name       Part Name  Quantity  
Order1           Part11     11  
Order1           Part12     12  

Order2           Part21     22 
Order2           Part22     22  
Order2           Part23     23
```

Answer (score -1):

It is called grouping and have a look at

- c-sharpcorner.com article ["Grouping in Datagrid in WPF"](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-in-datagrid-in-wpf/) .

It explains it pretty nicely. Basically you have to wrap your collection in a ListCollectionView and define the GroupDescription. Hope this helps!

```
ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(myOrders);
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(OrderName);
DataGrid.ItemSource = collection;
```

Comment: @MangoCrysis, your answer might be a helpful hint for keywords but its code cannot be used. I do not have any DataGrid in app referenced in my question. This was a request for help and clarifications but not for additional puzzle solving and guessing game

Comment: @GennadyVanin--ГеннадийВанин Since you mentioned that DataGrid has a collapse/expand option I thought you were open to using one. It would be the easiest way to solve your problem of having sorted columns.

Comment: I am open but: 1)I didn't mention DataGrid in my question, only in update in response to your answer. 2)The code from your article depends on reference to WPFToolKit and cannot be copy-pasted or downlaoded without registering at that site; 3) It still doesn't align the first row with the first line of data and proposed by you solution is not new to me. I removed my upvote since: 1)I lost my time b/c you insisted on nonexistent features; 2)I disliked your reference to my words I have never used and your free reformulating my question. When I have questions about DataGrid, I shall ask about it

Comment: @GennadyVanin--ГеннадийВанин My apologies for the confusion! I misunderstood the question. I was just trying to help and I'm kind of new to this. Thanks!